# Boot fail 12.04 on 3.5.0-47

Tags: boot

After updating Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Lenovo W530 about two weeks ago, I have encountered numerous booting errors. My most recent (and default) version is 3.5.0-47 generic.

The screen goes to scrolling text and then locks up. Sometimes it goes through to the UI login page and freezes (although cursor can still be moved). Other times it goes to a black screen with the cursor.

Logging in via older versions of Linux seems to work sporadically. Sometimes a 3.6 version will allow me to login, other times it won't (goes to the same scrolling text and locking up as described above). The same can be said for all other older versions that are listed.

In another askubuntu post, the problem seemed to stem from WLAN0 settings. According to the post once it is disabled, the system is able to boot again, although this would mean that wireless internet would be disabled.

[12.04 LTS - Recent update: Fails to boot with version 3.8.0-37 generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431040/12-04-lts-recent-update-fails-to-boot-with-version-3-8-0-37-generic)

Unfortunately I do not have the option of connecting my machine to the internet via cable - it relies solely on wifi internet.

Another problem I have encountered since installing Ubuntu on my machine (over a year ago) is that my wifi connection is erratic and sometimes simply cannot connect to the router. My windows partition has no such problems. At first I thought that there would not be a relationship between my 12.04 wifi problems and this new booting error, however the aforementioned post's solution of disabling WLAN0 has made me think otherwise.

I am not a tech savvy Linux user. Happy to provide more information if I can get instructions on how to provide relevant details.

PS I have not been able to set up static IP for my W530. Setting up a static IP resolved wifi issues I was having with my nexus 7 tablet with the current router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticing that most other Ubuntu 12.04 users were using 3.8, I decided to try upgrading to that kernel as well.

During the installation process I encountered a ndiswrapper error.

I then decided to update to kernel 3.11 and encountered the ndiswrapper error again.

I followed these instructions by Chili555:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967383

and executed this command:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9

I then reinstalled 3.11 and Ubuntu seems to be booting normally again. There is some scrolling text which is only shown on a black screen for approx. 1 or 2 seconds. They are only several lines, the first of which reads something like "no caching mode found".

However the text does not lock up, and fortunately goes through to the UI login page.

Wifi is still behaving erratically. Wicd shows that signal strength can fluctuate between 17 - 92% within a minute.

Hope this post helps others who might be encountering the same issue.

EDIT: Wifi is behaving more erratically than before. Probably due to reinstalling ndiswrapper..... 
EDIT #2: Okay it's two days since resolving the boot error. My wifi is behaving worse than before. Disconnecting every 2 minutes and very slow when connected - new drivers have been installed for my wifi card haven't helped. HOWEVER the boot error has not returned.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried booting without the wlan? Although you cannot connect to the Internet, you at least can confirm the problem is coming from the combination including your wlan card.

If this does work: *(If your current wlan adapter is pci, maybe you can remove it and)* borrow someone elses USB wifi-adapter and plug it in when (successfully) booted up and try to connect to the Internet than.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

Would you have instructions on how to boot without wlan and then to restore it once the test is done?