# Ubuntu 16.04 Kernel Damaged

Tags: dual-boot

I recently dual-booted my dell inspiron 15 laptop.  Everything worked perfectly (both OS Windows 10 & Ubuntu 16.04).  However my machine froze due to flash video during an Ubuntu update.  Now my grub menu still appears, however when I want to boot into Ubuntu, all I get is a blank purple screen.  I used the Ubuntu LiveDVD to install and run Boot-Repair, but that did not fix the problem.  I would appreciate any pointers on how to fix this, as it is likely to happen again in the future. Thanks...

**UPDATE:** At the grub OS selection screen, I went to "advanced boot options for ubuntu".  From there I selected the earliest available kernel for my machine along with (recovery mode).  At this point, I ran the "dpkg" option, then later I also checked the file system.  Currently, I can successfully boot into normal ubuntu using my earliest kernel ( "ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-51-generic ), however anytime I try to boot into ubuntu normally using the latest kernel ( "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-52-generic" ), I still see nothing but a purple screen.  Any recommendations?

NOTE: Loading ubuntu with the latest kernel and recovery mode doesn't work. I see:

> BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
>   Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
>   (initramfs)  .... 
>     This last part never completes, it just keeps repeating various things about the hardware...

Comment: "ubuntu froze... now by grub" wait, what happened in between the freeze and getting to GRUB?

Comment: first I re-booted thinking maybe I would have broken packages to clean up, instead the grub executed properly, and I get the blank purple screen.  Then I tried "Boot-Repair" but that did not help.

Comment: Can you provide us with some error logs or a screen shot of the boot up sequence

Comment: I hope my update above was a bit more clear...

Answer (score 2):

The trick to solve the problem was to simply boot into my earlier kernel, then use the terminal to [Reinstall the Latest Kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253244/reinstall-latest-kernel). Now everything is running smoothely again