# Failed to load any OS after installing Ubuntu in my Asus ROG laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation

I booted my USB device to install Ubuntu on my Asus ROG laptop which already had Windows 10. During installation I followed these steps:

I booted my USB and got a menu like

- Try Ubuntu without installing
- Install Ubuntu
- Install Ubuntu (safe graphics)

I went with the 3rd option.

At the partitioning stage I selected a disk which I'd created before for Ubuntu with 50 gb space and selected ext4 and then clicked on install.

After install it restarts and a pop up appeared saying remove installing medium and press enter and I ejected my usb. After that it opened the BIOS and in the boot menu it doesn't show any boot options like Windows Boot Manager or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Grub menu should appear if you press and hold Shift during loading Grub, if you boot using BIOS. When your system boots using UEFI (default on recent computers), press Esc.

If you get to the menu, you might want to press E to edit it. Move to the end of line beginning with "linux" and remove the "quiet" part. I would suggest you add "nomodeset" near that point. This is a workaround a bug that affects DRM somewhere between linux kernel 5.3.0 and that was fixed in 5.3.8: "Can't calculate constants, dotclock = 0!". nomodeset will make you impossible to change screen resolution however. You can then boot your modified (only for this time) version with Ctrl-X. This spans of "broken for some people" versions of Linux is what you will find in most recent version of Linux, like Ubuntu 19.10.

If this have helped you, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1185715/1011886 on how to fix it for a long time.

Comment: I add nomodeset and enters in linux , but now it only shows ubuntu not windows boot manager. How can i load windows boot mamager

Comment: Things i tried : Update grub in terminal , open recovery mode and update grub carefully, make usb bootable with boot repair disk but when i boot it was stuck at some screen says "Found RAPL domain package"

Comment: My ssd partition is not their when i check with fdisk -l