# screen freeze after upgrading to 19.10 from 19.04

Tags: screen, freeze

I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 . Upgrade was done via update manager . I am using amd radeon as a graphics driver. my screen is freeze. i am unable to do any things. i used everything available on internet but still problem is same.using advance option with old kernel 5.0.0.31 is working but when i used kernel 5.3.0-24 its freeze with purple color.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of a Linux kernel (DRM) bug that affects i3 and i5 (HD 620) graphics.
19.10 use a broken version... between 5.3.0 and 5.3.7, it is fixed in 5.3.8.
So you have to edit kernel parameters to set nomodeset to be able to change linux kernel version. And to edit grub, you may have to press shift or Esc while booting, select the version to boot, press E to edit it.
See https://askubuntu.com/a/1185715/1011886 to see how to test different versions of Linux.

Comment: my kernel is 5.0.0-31-generic

Comment: why ubuntu team is not find any solution for this problem.